# 'then' expected near '=' en la linea 21

Tags: lua

```
z = 1
a = 1
b = 1
c = 1
d = 1
e = 1
f = 1
g = 1
h = 1
i = 1
digits = {"","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"," ","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"}



for j=1,38,0 do

--run_cmd es una funcion personalizada
run_cmd("owner " .. digits[a] .. digits[b] .. digits[c] .. digits[d] .. digits[e] .. digits[f] .. digits[g] .. digits[h] .. digits[i] .. digits[j])
a = a+1

if a=38
then
b = b+1
a = 1
end

if b = 38
then c = c+1
b=1
end

if c = 38
then d = d+1
c=1
end

if d = 38
then e = e+1
end

if e = 38
then f = f+1
e=1
end

if f = 38
then g = g+1
f = 1
end

if g = 38
then h = h+1
g=1
end

if h = 38
then i = i+1
h=1
end

if i = 38
then j = j+1
i = 1
end
```

> me sale 'then' expected near '=' en la linea 21

estoy haciendo un script para toribash

Answer (score 0):

Para comparar variables en [lua](/questions/tagged/lua) debes usar el doble igual (`==`). Si usas un solo igual (`=`) estás asignando un valor, lo que no está permitido dentro de un `if`, de ahí el error. Querías hacer esto:

```
if a == 38 then
    b = b + 1
    a = 1
end

if b == 38 then
    c = c+1
    b = 1
end

if c == 38 then
    d = d + 1
    c = 1
end

if d == 38 then
    e = e + 1
end

if e == 38 then
    f = f + 1
    e = 1
end

if f == 38 then
    g = g + 1
    f = 1
end

if g == 38 then
    h = h + 1
    g = 1
end

if h == 38 then
    i = i + 1
    h = 1
end

if i == 38 then
    j = j + 1
    i = 1
end
```